How many ways can $1$ be written as a sum of three rational squares?
I am trying to find the number of ways $1$ can be written as a sum of three rational squares i.e.
$1 = \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right) ^2 + \left(\dfrac{c}{d}\right) ^2 + \left(\dfrac{e}{f}\right) ^2$
where, $a, b, c, d, e$, and $f$ are natural numbers.

Is there any reason to believe this is not infinite?

How many rational points are there on the unit sphere? Countably infinite. Cause the rationals are dense... and countably infinite.

@Mason well, that's not enough to prove it.  There aren't infinitely many rational points on $3=x^2+y^2$, though rational points are dense in the plane.  What you can show is that, if there's one, there are infinitely many.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple

@lulu. Ty. My intuition is instructively wrong. There are infinitely many algebraic solutions. And we have demonstrated infinite rational solutions after: $0^2+0^2+1^2=1$

@Mason  Yes, once you find one you can project from that one.

Lots of ways, maybe?

This is clearly infinite.  As one set of examples:
$$\left(\tfrac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)+1}\right)^2 + \left(\tfrac{2n(n+1)}{2n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)+1}\right)^2+\left(\tfrac{2n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)}{2n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)+1}\right)^2 =1$$ for all positive integer $n$.  When $n=1$ it gives $\left(\tfrac{3}{13}\right)^2 + \left(\tfrac{4}{13}\right)^2+\left(\tfrac{12}{13}\right)^2 =1$ while with $n=2$ it gives $\left(\tfrac{5}{85}\right)^2 + \left(\tfrac{12}{85}\right)^2+\left(\tfrac{84}{85}\right)^2 =1$, etc.

It is well-known that there are an infinite number of primitive Pythagorean quadruples: integers $a,b,c,d$ with $\gcd(a,b,c,d)=1$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$.  This follows from the existence of parameterisations such as that found here.
Dividing the terms of such a quadruple by $d^2$ we have:
$$(a/d)^2+(b/d)^2+(c/d)^2=1$$
